# How Should we use Azure key vault in Function App?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am planning to use azure key vault in my Azure Function App.

I can see there are below two ways we can use key vault in Azure Function App:

a. Using Reference variable in Configurations

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={copied identifier for the username secret})
```

b. Using .NET SDK

```
Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
Azure.Identity
```

Example(using .NET SDK):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string secretName = "mySecret";

            string keyVaultName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_NAME");
            var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

            Console.Write("Input the value of your secret > ");
            string secretValue = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Creating a secret in " + keyVaultName + " called '" + secretName + "' with the value '" + secretValue + "` ...");

            client.SetSecret(secretName, secretValue);

            Console.WriteLine(" done.");

            Console.WriteLine("Forgetting your secret.");
            secretValue = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Your secret is '" + secretValue + "'.");

            Console.WriteLine("Retrieving your secret from " + keyVaultName + ".");

            KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);

            Console.WriteLine("Your secret is '" + secret.Value + "'.");

            Console.Write("Deleting your secret from " + keyVaultName + " ...");

            client.StartDeleteSecret(secretName);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine(" done.");

        }
```

But my question is, How should i decide which one I should use?

Comment: Like it was mentioned in the comments, you don't even need to install the AKV into your Azure Functions. There are more details here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960764/how-to-modify-iconfiguration-natively-injected-in-azure-functions/63124002#63124002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Key Vault reference is of the form `@Microsoft.KeyVault({referenceString})`, which is **only applied on azure portal**. While the code sample you provided **works well both in portal and local**.

For key vault reference, you need to **create a system-assigned managed identity** for your function app and enable the "Get" permission on this function's service principle for keyvault. While the example **use the logged in user as credential**, you only need to enable "Get" permission on user for azure keyvault.

Comment: So then should i use .NET SDK?

Comment: and also which one is the preferred way to implement key vault in function app?

Comment: If you want to test in local and portal, I recommend you use .net sdk.