# Azure Functions Not able to hit HttpTrigger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have a simple Azure function with HttpTrigger like so:

```
[FunctionName("Heartbeat")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Heartbeat(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "heartbeat")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Received heartbeat request");
    var status = await _healthCheck.CheckHealthAsync();

    return new OkObjectResult(Enum.GetName(typeof(HealthStatus), status.Status));
}
```

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=false",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "*****"
    },

    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "ServiceDb": "Server=.;Initial Catalog=Acquire;Integrated Security=True;"
    },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
```

When i run the function locally I'm able to hit a breakpoint inside Heartbeat() and get 200OK. However, when it's deployed to Azure, It does not work and I get 404 Not Found.

**Local:**

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

What is the problem? why can't I execute an HttpTrigger?

Also, is there a way to view local.settings.json configururation in Azure? I though these settings would somehow populate from local.settings.json in Azure (like connection strings)-yet they're blank. Is there a way to show these settings in Azure?

[image]

Comment: Is AZURE windows or linux?  Instead of Localhost try the machine name (or IP).  On linux the IP address is not the same as in windows.

Comment: I would verify the URL is correct  it will look like this  https://YourAppName.azurewebsites.net/api/Heartbeat  notice it starts with https://

Comment: Url is correct. i verified and re-verified and when i go to the url (without the '...azurewebsites.net/api/heartbeat' i get the 404. Without /api/heartbeat I get "your function is up and running"

Comment: In order to configure this you need to add the settings 1 by 1 to the Configuration in azure. Some details are here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960764/how-to-modify-iconfiguration-natively-injected-in-azure-functions/63124002#63124002)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. My issue was that Runtime version was set to: ~1 instead of ~3. Another change I had to make for IOptions to bind is edit **project**, and modify these options:

```
<Content Include="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</Content>
```

[image]

To make logging work:
https://nuggets.hammond-turner.org.uk/2019/10/tuesday-quickie-ilogger-in-azure.html

I added this and now I see all logs fine:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "ServiceLogger": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

but all the answers from other users got me on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to view local.settings.json configururation in Azure?

There is no `local.settings.json` in Azure, hence the name "local".

You should add settings with the same names to your App Settings.

Comment: Stephen, do you mean add them manually in Azure? What about using IOptions<SomeClass> settings that are in local.settings.json? how would that be constructred? BTW> I really enjoyed your Concurrency in C# Cookbook :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#customizing-configuration-sources

Comment: Does reading my configuration in Azure before I setup my configuration in Azure count as a Concurrency Problem?  </sarc>

Comment: @ShaneKm: In Azure Functions, `IOptions<T>` [binds to the application settings by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings). If you create the function in the portal, you can add app settings in the portal. If you create the function via Bicep/ARM, then you can add app settings in your Bicep/ARM file.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option for azure to give you the function url. Should look something like this
[image]

Comment: You can even test that trigger on then `Code + Test` page without leaving the azure portal. It Should work, if not then surround the entry method with a try catch block and log the error